# Is there a way to get all files and folders by sending one HTTP request?

Tags: box-api

for google drive, i can make a simple request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files
```

reference link: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list

I was thinking if box-api can do the same for me.

Comment: is still box doesn't provide all data ?

Answer (score 1):

The v2 API does not currently support this.  For what it's worth, Google's support for this is somewhat unique among the big storage providers -- Dropbox and SkyDrive won't do it either.

Comment: As an aside, this just isn't really practical to provide. A non-trivial number of Box users have accounts with files and folders number in the hundreds of thousands and millions.